# Facebook "Like Button" shows count with incorrect format

Tags: facebook-like

I added a "Like button" in www.6bebes.com but it shows counts in incorrect format (1,2000 instead of 1,2K). If I change "connect.facebook.net/es_LA/all.js#xfbml=1" with "connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1" it shows correct but in english. I saw other sites in spanish working ok with es_LA but I don't know why my button fails. It fails also in http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ if you put "http://www.facebook.com/6bebes" as "url to like"

Comment: Are you talking about the "Like Button": http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ or the "Like Box": http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/ the box is for liking your Facebook account from your website and the like button is to like the webpage it is on (from what I have worked out). It might help someone answer if you specify this? :)

Comment: is about  http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like "Like Button" because I want the "Like Button" behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was reported a bug on May 4th. Here you can follow it.

http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/355302524526776